Возможно ли объединить эти два запроса в один?
Первый запрос получает количество заказов с "utm_source" и разбивает их по дням.
SELECT COUNT(id) AS count_orders_utm, DATE_FORMAT(`at`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`
FROM shop_orders
WHERE userinfo LIKE '%utm\_source%' AND DATE(`at`) >= '2024-06-28' AND state NOT IN ('отклонен', '')
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(`at`)
ORDER BY `at`;


Второй запрос получает общее количество заказов по дням.
SELECT COUNT(id) AS orders_all, DATE_FORMAT(`at`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`
FROM shop_orders
WHERE DATE(`at`) >= '2024-06-28' AND state NOT IN('отклонен', '')
GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(`at`)
ORDER BY `at`;


Возможно ли их как-то обединить в один и на выходе получить общую таблицу:

"Общее количество заказов в конкретный день"
"Кол-во" заказов с "utm_source" в поле userinfo
Дата


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?

Оба запроса логически (и синтаксически) некорректны. Читать про группировку вообще и ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY в MySQL в частности. Обсуждать возможность объединить две ошибки в одну большую не имеет смысла.

@Akina благодарю за ответ. Я только в самом начале пути и возможно, для меня все не так очевидно, как для вас. Не могли бы вы, как пример, показать как должен выглядеть первый запрос? Хотелось бы понять, в чем заключается логическая и синтаксическая ошибка. Ведь на выходе я получаю ожидаемый результат и вроде все работает.

Хотелось бы понять, в чем заключается логическая и синтаксическая ошибка. Ну представьте, что в данных если запись за 1 июня и за 1 июля. Вы группируете по DAYOFMONTH(`at`) - т.е. для обеих записей он равен 1, и они попадут в одну группу. Вы просите вывести DATE_FORMAT(`at`, '%d.%m.%Y'). Для этих записей это выражение даст разный результат. Но в выходном наборе должна быть только одна запись. Из какой исходной записи из этих двух её следует получить?
